# Debian Wheezy : /etc/ssl/certs/ contains a lot of certificats

Tags: debian

I need some help with my server, I have a debian wheezy installed. I just checked the folder /etc/ssl/certs/ and I found a lot of certificats like :

XRamp_Global_CA_Root.pem

Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority.pem

etc ...

It's normal or my server get hacked ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal

It's the standard list of trusted certificates

Comment: To expand a little, they're Certificate Authorities, rather than regular certificates.  eg, that Verisign CA you listed, is how your system will ensure that any cert which claims to be signed by Verisign, actually was.